# Where to put the code to compile new kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel

I am new to Kernel development. I want to compile my Helloworld.c, but when I tried to compile it through gcc, it shows lot of errors as it is not able to locate the  and other linux module. So just tell me where should I put my module code in the linux kernel code.

Comment: See these [question][1] for an answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714395/compiling-a-kernel-module-header-problems-makefile-problems

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Linux Module Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/) in particular the chapter 11