# Can't figure out how to compile Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have been trying to figure out how to compile a kernel module. I started with http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf to learn. I then found [Compiling a kernel module, header problems, makefile problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714395/compiling-a-kernel-module-header-problems-makefile-problems) to get my makefile going. After running make. I get the following output:

```
    Building target module 2.6 kernel.
    PLEASE IGNORE THE "Overriding SUBDIRS" WARNING
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.el6.i686/build SUBDIRS=/root/kerntest/hello modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686'
```

I see the .ko file, but don't see any kernel messages showing the module was activated. I also checked in /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686/extra but there is nothing there. I also tried 'dmesg' and 'lsmod' but didn't see it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am trying this on CentOS 6.5

Comment: Did you load the module? I.e. run `insmod` or `modprobe`?

Comment: I just tried insmod. Thanks, that worked. Put this up as an official answer and I will give it the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually load the module into the kernel after compiling by using `insmod` or `modprobe` :)